# Creality Halot One Z axis inaccuracy

Tags: z-axis, resin, creality-halot-one

I'm having issues with the accuracy of the Z-axis of my Creality Halot One. X and Y seem pretty close (as you'd expect for resin).

Firstly, it seems to not move and/or overprint the first 0.6 mm or so of the model, which as well as being inaccurate, also creates little flares. This error was tested and confirmed by creating a measuring stick and printing.  I could theoretically get around this by raising the part on supports, but as I am doing a flat surface, I can't afford to have the "pimples" generated by the support on this surface (and neither can I rotate for the same reasons - other flat surfaces).

Secondly, it appears that the Z-axis is under-height by about 10 %. What should be circular features appear as ovals, and my best measuring shows the Z-axis comes out about 10 % short of the design.

I have re-levelled, and all that basic stuff.
I have checked that it has the latest firmware.
I have tried different slicers, and they all have the same issue, so I'm pretty sure it's not a slicing issue.
Similarly, I have tried different line heights. (0.05 mm, 0.025 mm, etc.), they still come short, and still lose the first 0.6 mm.

There seems very little of any practical nature that can be done to fix this.

Has anyone experienced similar, on this or other resin printers, and has anyone discovered a fix? Or have any worthwhile suggestions?